# Is it okay to use the word "letter" instead of "e-mail" regarding to e-mail correspondence?

Tags: email, correspondence

Could you please advise is it okay to use the word "letter" instead of "e-mail" regarding to e-mail correspondence?

For example, is it okay to use the word "letter" in the following phrase if we are talking about e-mail correspondence: "thank you for your letter".

Best wishes,
Anton

Comment: It's not common, but anyone who read it would understand what you meant from context. More commonly, I see "note", as in "thanks for your note", but this is typically only applied to short emails (congratulatory, conciliatory, or condolences, usually). So the real question is: *why* do you want to use "letter" instead of "email" or "mail" or "message" etc?

Comment: Stick to: "Thank you for your email" to avoid *any* possible misunderstanding. People still send letters via mail or post (snail mail) and the recipient might ask himself "When did I post a letter?" Unlikely, but the term *email* or *e-mail* (if you're old school) is no longer considered informal or "chatty".

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have seen the term *e-letter* used for a formal item of correspondence. One problem with e-mail, when it comes to legal correspondence, is that you have no proof of delivery. An old fashioned letter can be sent by Recorded Delivery or a Certificate of Posting obtained from the Post Office. Hence there have been occasions when I have sent a letter in the post, but for speed of transmission attached a copy to an email at the same time.

Comment: I would say use "note" or "email".  "Letter" could be confusing.

Answer (score 4):

It is best to reserve the term "letter" for actual paper letters sent by "snail mail" (post).

Call an instance of email a "message".  (If you simply say "your email" you are not specifying which message; there may have been several.) "Thank you for your message {sent/which I received} on Friday."

Or mangle the language and pretend it's AN email. (The majority of Americans do, though they don't call a letter "a mail".)

"thank you for your latest email" (actually you have no idea whether it was her latest email; she might have sent and received several other messages since sending that message to you)